# I am trying to install tensor flow but keep running into errors

Tags: python, keras, pip

Hi I am Trying to pip install tensor flow on my MacBook and I keep running into this error  `./venv/bin/activate.fish:9: parse error near` end'` I am pretty new to the Mac OS so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Errors without context are meaningless, you need to tell us what command triggered this error, and include the whole output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

activate.fish is if you are using a fish shell, you are probably using bash since you are on MacOs, try one of the corresponding commands frome the official tutorial.
[image]

reference : https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos

Answer (score 0):

Okay so for beginners the the TensorFlow tutorial on how to download TensorFlow for Mac OS  is hot garbage in my opinion instead watch this video   which is better for those of us who are new to actually downloading things to our own computers. [TensorFlow for Mac OS video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CO-ND1FTOU)